# Vue.js workflow from Vue.js 1 to 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have followed the Vue.js lessons from laracasts when Vue.js 1 came out and I used to do something like this:

```
import Comments from './components/Comments.vue';
import Upload from './components/Upload.vue';

new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    components: {
            Comments,
            Upload,
            Preview,
            Algolia,
        },

    etc,
});
```

This allowed me to kind of 'sprinkle' components all over my application. I can no longer bind to the body though because Vue replaces the content and also throws an error message saying you shouldn't bind to the body or html.

I followed a couple of lessons for Vue.js 2 but how can I replicate this workflow in the Vue.js 2 manner? I loved just binding to the body and having the option to place a component here and there with the custom tags.

Comment: Make it `<body><div id="app"></div></body>` and bind to `#app`?

Comment: @ceejayoz wouldn't this clear out the entire app wrapper though? You would have effectively shushed the warning but wouldn't my entire body still be gone?

Comment: @Stephan-v nope! For the same reason binding on `body` currently doesn't clear out the entire app. Tbh Vue 2 doesn't handle the sprinkling of components through an app as well as Vue 1 does but it works for the most part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the same "sprinkling" approach and all we did was change it from `'body'` to `'#app'`.

We also added a wrapping element inside that had this id to basically replicate `body`. (https://github.com/onespacemedia/project-template/blob/develop/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.package_name%7D%7D/templates/base.html#L62)

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

We use Jinja2 for our templating language and have found when a variable that doesn't resolve in Jinja2 it tanks Vue as well as i think Vue tries to use it.

I believe it takes everything inside `#app` after initial render and converts it to virtual dom. This doesn't effect anything from what i've seen though so you can happily just add the wrapping class inside `body` and use it the same as Vue 1

Comment: I was using the runtime version and wit the runtime version you can't actually use template tags inside your html. Guess I got that solved.

Comment: Gotcha, we use the runtime version too but behind webpack with `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` to turn the `.vue` files into render functions (https://github.com/onespacemedia/project-template/blob/develop/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.package_name%7D%7D/assets/js/main.js) and (https://github.com/onespacemedia/project-template/blob/develop/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/gulpfile.js/lib/webpack-multi-config.js)

Comment: @DabGamble whenever I use `$mount()` I am instantly getting a standalone build though it looks like you are doing pretty much the same. I can't see why you would be getting a runtime build, just by looking at your main.js file.

Comment: @Stephan-v if you check the 2nd link, the webpack config, you can see the vue alias that allows it

Comment: the `'vue': 'vue/dist/vue'` in your webpack config points to the standalone version though. The one that is not even intended for webpack use because that should be `vue/dist/vue.common.js` so I am sorry but I still don't see where you are getting a runtime build from. Sorry to keep on bitching but I would love to get this figured out :P

Comment: I'm just doing what Evan said :) https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215#issuecomment-238095102. It resolved my problem with `vue-loader` and webpack